# Clean solution to avoid error caused by selection

Tags: r

I try to do something like

```
df[<very-long-and-complicated-selection>,]$foo <- "bar"
```

This works well, if there are rows matching the selection.

If not I get an error message

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "foo", value = "bar") :
>   replacement has 1 row, data has 0

However, my code is designed in a way, where no matching is possible.

Is there a clean, short and easy solution to avoid these (and only these) errors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
df[<very-long-and-complicated-selection>, "foo"] <- "bar"
```

ie, make the assignment into the dataframe treating it as a 2-dimensional object, rather than as a list.

Comment: great! very clean and easy solution! Thank you!

Comment: Just noticed: doesn't work with an empty data.frame -- `d = data.frame(n=numeric(), c=character())` `d[d$c == "a", "n"] <- 5`, works fine with `d = data.frame(n=1:3, c=c("b", "b", "b"))`

Answer (score 0):

Use [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

```
d %>% dplyr::mutate(n = ifelse(c == 'a', 5, n))
```